# Crash on [[NSDate alloc] init]

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

My code is pretty simple:

```
NSDate * curDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
return (int64_t)([curDate timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000);
```

However I got market crash issue with the following stack trace:

> Thread 227 Crashed: 0   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x000000018d2af4bc __abort + 176 (abort.c:140) 1   libsystem_c.dylib 
>     0x000000018d2af4bc __abort + 176 (abort.c:140) 2   libsystem_c.dylib 
>     0x000000018d2af40c abort + 152 (abort.c:99) 3
>   libsystem_malloc.dylib            0x000000018d37fa5c nanozone_error + 332
>   (nano_malloc.c:82) 4   libsystem_malloc.dylib
>     0x000000018d381be0 _nano_malloc_check_clear + 412 (nano_malloc.c:660)
>   5   libsystem_malloc.dylib            0x000000018d380be8 nano_calloc + 80
>   (nano_malloc.c:892) 6   libsystem_malloc.dylib
>     0x000000018d372168 malloc_zone_calloc + 152 (malloc.c:1367) 7
>   libsystem_malloc.dylib            0x000000018d3720ac calloc + 40
>   (malloc.c:1643) 8   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x000000018cdaf624
>   class_createInstance + 76 (objc-runtime-new.mm:6376) 9
>   CoreFoundation                    0x000000018e374c9c __CFAllocateObject +
>   28 (NSObject.m:1005) 10  CoreFoundation
>     0x000000018e2472d4 +[__NSDate __new:] + 20 (NSDate.m:67) 11 
>   CoreFoundation                    0x000000018e2472b0
>   -[__NSPlaceholderDate initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:] + 112 (NSDate.m:199)

Any idea on what might be going wrong in alloc and possible ways of fixing it?

Comment: what are you running it on ?

Comment: Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2

Comment: OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.2 (14C92)

Comment: Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000018d2af4bc
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  227

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
NSDate * curDate = [NSDate date];
```